# Trying to set up WebCam Recording in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, webcam, video-streaming

The actual recording part I have figured out to completion. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out a way to automatically add a number to my file output.
For example:

Stream_00.mp4
Stream_01.mp4
Stream_02.mp4
Stream_03.mp4
etc.

The default output string will just overwrite the previous file.

I'm running VLC on linux so it seems like it might be easy to do with the "stream output string".

Here is my stream output string:

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mpga,
ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
:file{mux=mp4,dst=/home/myname/Videos/stream} :sout-keep
```